# Why is there array copy method in class System?

Tags: java, system, arrays

Why is there array copy method in class System? It seems it is not much with system stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's there for historical reasons: it's there since JDK 1.0, while the Java class `Arrays` where this method logically belongs has not been introduced until Java 1.2 release.